# How to populate Buttons from ListAdapter In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listadapter

I am writing a questionaire app wherein four answers from SQLLite db need to be added to four normal buttons (not radiobButtons) in the view.

I am querying the database and getting the results as cursor.I am unable to attach the results to four buttons,but am able to attach the same to List View as below

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT Answer From'+SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME+'", null);
                   if (c != null ) {
          if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
            String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer"));
            results.add(firstName);
           }while (c.moveToNext());
          } 
         }

         this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
```

How do I attach the cursor results to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by creating a DB Adapter using factory pattern and creating the buttons dynamically.